# reduce the height of only one row out of multiple rows

Tags: html, css, svg, rect

I have multiple charts in my webpage.I want to decrease only the height of **second row of first chart**, is that possible? Or can i decrease the height of the **second row colored bar** in first chart?

Please find the demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/QXjNsM8z0jbU2gB3Hq31?p=preview

Generated code:
[image]
I tried with below code, but it is applying for all the rows, i want to only reduce height of only second row of first chart.

sample code:

```
#t1 svg rect {
    height:4px;
}
```

Comment: you want to reduce height of those rects???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29578252/592355 might be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nth-of-type to do this:

```
#t1 svg text:nth-of-type(2) {
height:4px
}
```

Edit

```
rect:nth-of-type(2) {height:4px}
```

[W3 Schools CSS :nth-of-type()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

Comment: I want to reduce the height of rect or complete 2nd row of chart1 only.

Comment: Try using rect:nth-of-type(2) {height:4px}

Comment: If that causes problems then you can try something like

    #chart1 rect:nth-of-type(2) {height:4px}